# While downloading getcontentlength() returns -1 in Android

Tags: java, android, web-services, web-applications, download

I am working on an Android app, where I am downloading a file and show the progress in a progress bar. For this I need to know the length of the file.So i am using the below mentioned code. But it returns -1.It works fine with local server. But once it moved to live server, the issue started. So anyone can help me out.

```
URL url = new URL("URL TO DOWNLOAD");
URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
HttpURLConnection httpUrlConn = (HttpURLConnection) conection;
httpUrlConn.connect();
int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();
```

Here i am getting file length as -1. Why does it happen? Is there a way to avoid it and get the correct length?

Answer (score 0):

Check your URL path page i think there are no any data present on that page.

Answer (score 0):

read this.[documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#getContentLength%28%29).

getContentLength() Returns the value of the content-length header field.

the content length of the resource that this connection's URL references, or -1 if the content length is not known.

Comment: If the same url hits through java app, its working fine. But its not working with iphone and android.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely same thing happens to me all the time, too. This -1 really screws up with our progress bars, doesn't it? You know what I do? I rename the file (yes, right on the server) and then change it back. The problem disappears. Pure magic... Also, there's a workaround, fast and dirty: if you know precise length of the offending file you can simply replace -1 with that number. Yes, just substitute it. For example, my app downloads files from my personal site so I'm 100% sure that the files are in place. I also know their sizes to a byte. Hence:

```
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... aurl) {
        int realLOF = 1234567890;     // personally, I use an array element here 
        boolean badLOF = false;
        try {
             URL url = new URL(aurl[0]);
             URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
             connection.connect();

             int lengthOfFile = connection.getContentLength();
             if (lengthOfFile == -1) {
             lengthOfFile = realLOF;             // yeah, I know. Unhealthy :(
             badLOF = true;                  
            }
             Log.d("DL", "LOF: " + lengthOfFile + ", badLOF: " + badLOF);

        // your DL logic here

               } catch (Exception e) {
        // whatever
               }
            return null;
        }
    // my app runs batch downloads so I made a recursive loop:
    // DownloadFileAsync().execute(url) calls itself on onPostExecute(),
    // and that's how badLOF resets itself.
```

Naturally, this approach will work only if you can boss those files. Interestingly enough, the problem is 1) reproducible with the same files, and 2) apparently not related to the filesize per se: first of all, it happens both to big and small files (like 100MB and 1kB), and secondly, I experienced it only with HostMonster filehosters. No, I'm not driving at anything, I like the quality of their service. Simply wondering how to fix the broken axle, that's all...

HTH.